# C++ Compilation Error Non Class Type

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

In below I am getting error as error: request for member 'get_id' in '* it', which is of non-class type 'const Param* const'. What is the problem with below piece of code

```
bool SomeParams::is_default(int _id) const
{
        vector<const Param*> param_list;
        bool is_default = false;

        if( get_default_params(param_list) ) // This populates param_list
        {
                vector<const Param*>::const_iterator it = param_list.begin();

                for(;it!=param_list.end();++it)
                {
                        if( *it->get_id() == _id ) // get_id is function in Param object
                        {
                                is_default = true;
                                break;
                        }
                }
        }

        return is_default;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enclose `*it` in parenthesis: `(*it)->get_id()`.

Comment: it worked.. i tried it before posting the question it didn't worked.. may be your words have some magic :)

Answer (score 5):

Precendece of `->` (i.e member access operator) is higher than `*` (i.e indirection operator), so

```
*it->get_id();
```

is interpreted as:

```
*(it->get_id());
```

which causes compilation error.

What you need is this:

```
(*it)->get_id();
```

See this table:

- [C++ Operator Precedence](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/language/operator_precedence)

---

Two important points:

- The name of the parameter of the function starts with `_`, which according to the language specification, invokes undefined behavior. Names starting with an *underscore* are reserved. Don't use them.
- The function's name is `is_default`, and there is one variable inside the function, which is also `is_default`. Why don't you choose different name for the variable? That would increase the readability of your code.

Comment: I think double underscores are reserved. In out project single _ are reserved for function arguments. Regarding the function name yes I have to change them